# Visual Studio 2012 Intellisence Icon - Unknown Icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, icons, intellisense, git-extensions

This is not a programming question, but just curious to know.

I came across this new looking icon for a class variable. It has "1" sub-scripted to it. I'm using the singleton pattern. Is this the icon for singleton variable?

[image]

I looked up [this official list of icons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx), but didn't find the one in questions.

Just to add, I have Git Extensions plugin VS installed for source control.

Is there any official reference on such icons.

Comment: Quote: "If your project is included in a source control database, additional signal icons may be displayed to indicate source-control status, such as checked in or checked out.".  Makes it pretty relevant to mention what source control add-in you use.

Comment: I use Git Extension plugin for VS.

Comment: Don't tell me, put it in your question and pick an appropriate [tag] so other people that use that plugin can see it.

Comment: But I'm not sure if this icon is because of Git Extension. 
I've added the tag, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the static modifier overlay.
[image: Static Overlay defined in the visual studio image library pdf]
That simply indicates that the field/property is static. You can find a mostly complete package of visual studio 2012/2013/2015 icons [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx).

Separately the image service/catalog contains a complete list of icons used by visual studio 2015. If you have the VSSdk installed you can use the [image library viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt629250.aspx) application instead.